# Uncaught exception when installing webdriver plugin in jmeter

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jmeter

I am trying to add webdriver plugin to jmeter. I have downloaded and added the webdriver plugin named 'JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.1.1' to Jmeter2.7.But when I run the jmeter batch file in GUI mode I'm getting an uncaught exception:

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kg.apc.jmeter.gui.GuiBuilderHelper.strechButtonToComponent(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljavax/swing/JButton;)V. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory. See log file for details.
```

Comment: You're likely missing required jars webdriver jars in your classpath. How did you add webdriver plugin to jmeter? Did you check the log as suggested?

Comment: I have extracted the zip file and placed the jar files in lib folder into the jmeter\lib folder and the jar file in the ext folder into the jmeter\lib\ext folder.Is there anthing like I have to add a particular webdriver plugin(version) to jmeter of a particular version only?

Comment: Yes I have checked log it says:ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory
 at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:89)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:158)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeListener.displayPopUp(JMeterTreeListener.java:312)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeListener.mousePressed(JMeterTreeListener.java:258)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

> You need to run JMeter 2.12 or above with a Java 7 or above to use the plugins.

Always use the latest version of jmeter possible, to take advantage of big fixes and performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I launch Jmeter using Maven (or Gradle), like so and so I think it is a little more consistent that way:  https://github.com/djangofan/launch-jmeter

Just be careful using my Gradle launcher because the gradle plugins that support Jmeter are not yet mature.